# posting to pingomatic with curl is not allowed

Tags: php, curl, blogs

I posted to pingomatic using curl with code like this

```
$curl = curl_init($this->buildURL());
curl_exec($curl);
```

But got the reply

```
You are too awesome for Ping-o-matic
```

Why am I too awesome for Ping-o-matic?

**EDIT**

I am posting to pingomatic but not `POST`ing to pingomatic. Their setup just takes a simple `GET` request

Comment: Aparently Ping-o-matic sucks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pingomatic requires the user agent header be set. Adding this fixes the problem:

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0" );
```

The code would then look like

```
$curl = curl_init($this->buildURL());
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0" );
curl_exec($curl);
```

Source: http://www.krunk4ever.com/blog/2011/12/21/you-are-too-awesome-for-ping-o-matic/

Github project: https://github.com/DynamiX-Web-Design/DxPingomatic